# Properly instantiating a class assigned to a private static volatile variable using reflection and locking

Tags: c#, reflection, refactoring

So here's a contrived example of what I want to have improved or confirmed.

I'm using (my/i)BATIS.NET (a light-weight ORM/data mapper framework), and what I've got is a class with a static reference to each of the table mappers for a database. It works great, but there's so much repetition that I thought there might be an opportunity to greatly simplify the code. The class currently looks like so:

```
public sealed class MyRepository
{
    private static string _connectionString;

    private volatile static TableAbcMapper _tableAbcMapper;
    private volatile static TableXyzMapper _tableXyzMapper;
    // and about 30 more of these

    private MyRepository()
    {
    }

    public static void Init(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public static string ConnectionString
    {
        get { return _connectionString; }
    }

    public static TableAbcMapper TableAbc
    {
        get
        {
            if (_tableAbcMapper == null)
            {
                lock (typeof(TableAbcMapper))
                {
                    if (_tableAbcMapper == null)
                    {
                        _tableAbcMapper = new TableAbcMapper(_connectionString);
                    }
                }
            }
            return _tableAbcMapper;
        }
    }

    public static TableXyzMapper TableXyz
    {
        get
        {
            if (_tableXyzMapper == null)
            {
                lock (typeof(TableXyzMapper))
                {
                    if (_tableXyzMapper == null)
                    {
                        _tableXyzMapper = new TableXyzMapper(_connectionString);
                    }
                }
            }
            return _tableXyzMapper;
        }
    }

    // and about 30 more of these readonly properties
}
```

Every time I add or remove a table to the database I get to add a `private volatile static` field and that big ugly singleton-y property to the `MyRepository` class. My first idea was to make the properties call a generic instancing function within the class; something that looks like:

```
private static void InitMapper<TMapper>(TMapper instance) where TMapper : MyMapper
{
    lock (typeof(TMapper))
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TMapper), 
                new object[] { _connectionString }) as TMapper;
        }
    }
}
```

Then the public getters could be slightly reduced to:

```
public static TableXyzMapper TableXyz
{
    get
    {
        if (_tableXyzMapper == null)
        {
            InitMapper<TableXyzMapper>(_tableXyzMapper);
        }
        return _tableXyzMapper;
    }
}
```

But, I don't know if passing around volatile fields is such a great idea, and using `ref` or `out` with volatile fields is a no-no, and on top of all that it doesn't reduce the amount of code all that much.

What I'd like to do is completely refactor the `MyRepository` class so that it has no private fields and no public getters, and uses reflection to initialize all of the mappers right away instead of lazy-loading them. I wouldn't have to change any of the code that uses the `MyRepository` class as it would look exactly the same, but under-the-hood it would be a little different:

```
public sealed class MyRepository
{
    private MyRepository()
    {
    }

    public volatile static TableAbcMapper TableAbc = null;
    public volatile static TableXyzMapper TableXyz = null;

    public static void Init(string connectionString)
    {
        foreach (var fieldInfo in typeof(MyRepository).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static))
        {
            if (fieldInfo.GetValue(new MyRepository()) == null)
            {
                lock (fieldInfo.FieldType)
                {
                    if (fieldInfo.GetValue(new MyRepository()) == null)
                    {
                        fieldInfo.SetValue(new MyRepository(), 
                            fieldInfo.FieldType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(string) })
                                .Invoke(new object[] { connectionString }));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the only maintenance I have to do when new tables are added to the database is to add a new `public volatile static` field for it, and the reflection would take care of the rest.

**A few questions I have with this approach:**

- Is this approach functionally equivalent to the original class?
- Is there any danger in defining volatile variables using reflection?
- Is it as readable as the original class (assuming it's all commented)?

Lastly, if this is a question better suited for the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) site, I'm all for having it migrated (mods!).

Comment: This looks like the service locator pattern? Is that what you are intending?

Comment: It's not what I was intending, but I suppose this is a very simplified implementation of that pattern. Most of the heavy lifting is managed within the IBatis libraries, I'm just providing a way for the rest of my code to easily get at the table mappers.

Comment: Unless this is a fun thought experiment, it seems like using DI and a container would be simpler?

Comment: @RitchMelton: it may be :) The long and short of this is that I have a utility that generates all of the code for my data access layer, so I never have to touch this class. I wanted to see what ideas others had to reduce this file from thousands of lines of code to something less while maintaining a functional equivalent to my original example, but at the same time, learn more about reflection and whether my proposal is safe or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be not much shorter but since you already have an init method you can there create a lazy value which is created upon first access. The nice thing about Lazy (part of .NET 4) is that you can specify that the value can be created more than one time but its value is only published once (gives better perf).

```
class Program
    {
        static Lazy<string> _Lazy;
        static string _connectionString;

        public string LazyValue
        {
            get
            {
                return _Lazy.Value;
            }

        }

        public static void Init(string connectionString)
        {
            _connectionString = connectionString;
            _Lazy = new Lazy<string>(() => new string(connectionString.ToArray()), System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);
        }
```

It won´t get much shorter though.

Comment: That's an interesting look at it, unfortunately it'll be a long time before we can move to .NET 4 here :( .NET 3.5 for the foreseeable future.

Comment: You could copy the code from .Net 4 and use it with .NET 3 or you could make your own simple Lazy class which employs double checked locking during the construction.

Comment: I'm choosing this as an answer for now. I implemented my own thread-safe version of `Lazy<T>`. Using it reduces the lines of code to a third of what they were and it's very readable.